# How can I change from SQL Server Windows mode to mixed mode (SQL Server 2008)?

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server 2008 Express Edition, but by mistake I kept the Windows authentication mode.

Now I want to change that to SQL Server mixed mode. How can I do this?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can do it with SQL Management Studio -

> Server Properties - Security - [Server Authentication section] you check Sql
>   Server and Windows authentication mode

Here is the msdn source - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. Atlast I got the success after going thru the link.

Comment: @Sevtlozer , I am also use same link , i am also able to connect with sql server authentication on my system ,but i am not able to connect database server from networked computer . I think my sql server agen service is not start . I am not able to start that service please suggest me .

Comment: @Sushant Network access is disabled by default to sqlexpress, see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165647(v=sql.90).aspx) for how to enable

Comment: This does not work if you are unable to log into the server.

Comment: Whoaaaaa!!! after spending days...the above link resolved it. I was trying to connect through Windows Authentication but lots of exceptions I came across. But this link just made my day. Thanks a ton @Svetlozar Angelov

Comment: When I try to change the password by selecting SQL server authentication. I am getting following error **Cannot alter the login 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)**

Answer (score 29):

I had no success with other attempts on a SQL Server 2012. What I did was use SQL Server Management Studio to generate a script to change the value, and got this:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 2
GO
```

After that, I enabled the `sa` account using this:

```
ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE ;
GO
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = '<strongPasswordHere>' ;
GO
```

...then, I restarted the service, and everything worked!

Comment: Thanks for this tip

Comment: Nice one - especially for the command line invocation for the registry change. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

From this:
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2008/06/19/How-to-change-authentication-mode-in-SQL-Server.aspx

One can catch that you may change it through windows registry key

```
(SQLEXPRESS instance):

"Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLEXPRESS\LoginMode" = 2
```

... and restart service

Answer (score 13):

1. Open up SQL Server Management Studio and connect to your database server.
2. Right Click The Database Server and click Properties.
3. Set the Server Authentication to SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode.

Comment: When I try to change the password by selecting SQL server authentication. I am getting following error Cannot alter the login 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Answer (score 6):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx):

To change security authentication mode:

> In SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer, right-click the
>   server, and then click Properties.
>
> On the Security page, under Server authentication, select the new
>   server authentication mode, and then click OK.
>
> In the SQL Server Management Studio dialog box, click OK to
>   acknowledge the requirement to restart SQL Server.
>
> In Object Explorer, right-click your server, and then click Restart.
>   If SQL Server Agent is running, it must also be restarted.

To enable the SA login:

> In Object Explorer, expand Security, expand Logins, right-click SA,
>   and then click Properties.
>
> On the General page, you might have to create and confirm a password
>   for the login.
>
> On the Status page, in the Login section, click Enabled, and then
>   click OK.

Answer (score 3):

Open the registry and search for key `LoginMode` under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
```

Update the LoginMode value as 2.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Simple and easy -- doesn't require Management Studio overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you don't have access to SQL Server and now you are using mixed mode to enable sa or grant an account admin privileges, then it is far easier just to uninstall SQL Server and reinstall.