# linux php connect to Server 2008 running MS SQL Server Express

Tags: php, sql-server

i can connect from client PC to SQL Server Express using the following creds. in mgnt sudio:

```
server: 192.168.44.96\sqldb
auth: windows auth
user name: domain\user
pw: 1234!
```

Have a LAMP server trying to connect to the above SQL server, here's what the PHP looks like:

```
$server = '192.168.44.96\sqldb';
$username = 'domain\user';
$password = '1234!';
$database = 'testing123';
$connection = mssql_connect($server, $username, $password);
if($connection != FALSE){
    echo "Connected to the database server OK<br />";
}
else {
    die("Couldn't connect" . mssql_get_last_message());
}

if(mssql_select_db($database, $connection)){
    echo "Selected $database ok<br />";
}
    else {
    die('Failed to select DB');
}
```

the page displays 'couldn't connect' and the error.log says "unable to connect ot server: 192.168.44.96".

I have also set mssql.secure_connection = On in php.ini and restarted apache2.

any thoughts?

thanks!

Comment: We did this at my workplace, and we ended up hosting PHP on a windows box because theres no good drivers for MSSQL on Linux. We got it working but it took 30 secs to connect etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on the PHP part, I only know SQL Server.
But I can tell you: That's not how Windows authentication works.
You can't use Windows authentication and then pass user name and password explicitly to the server. You need to do one of these:

1. Use SQL Server authentication and pass user name and password explicitly
2. Use Windows authentication and **do not** pass user name and password - you will connect automatically with the active Windows user.

Since you're using a Linux server, I'm pretty sure that you can't use Windows authentication. So you have to use SQL authentication (which needs to be enabled on a fresh SQL Server installation), and you have to create an user on the SQL Server.

Comment: is there any way to modify the current sql server instance to use mixed mode auth?

Comment: Yes, see this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393654/how-to-change-from-sql-server-windows-mode-to-mixed-modesql-server-2008

Comment: awesome! changed to mixed mode, added an sql user, connected using sql auth and the new user creds. works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a default sqlexpress installation you probably need to configure your sql server to allow remote access connections.
Also I don't know if you can connect with windows auth. At your sql server you can also setup sql authentication and use uid=;pwd=.