# Microsoft sql server error 18456 login failed for user

Tags: sql-server

I have installed MSSQL 2012 on Windows 2012 Server using the following settings:

[image]

[image]

But when I try to login (The username is my local user that I log-on to windows 2012 server with) I get (default instance name = MSSQLSERVER):

[image]

[image]

I have looked at:

[How can I change from SQL Server Windows mode to mixed mode (SQL Server 2008)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393654/how-can-i-change-from-sql-server-windows-mode-to-mixed-mode-sql-server-2008)

http://vsstack.blogspot.in/2013/11/microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-login.html

but that guide assumes there is already a DB available that I can enable authentication for. This is not the case. What am I missing? Do I need to re-install MSSQL to select Mixed Mode?

EDIT: In this case it seems its only possible to change to Mixed Mode by messing around in the Registry, bummer:
http://www.top-password.com/knowledge/sql-server-authentication-mode.html

AND BUYING this
http://www.top-password.com/purchase.html

to update the sa password afterwards. Maybe they should consider writing that as a warning in the installation wizard!

It will take a couple of days to uninstall MSSQL 2012:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvjjU8nPrRc

So maybe the best solution is to re-install windows?

Comment: did you check your db server supports `windows authetication` or `mixed authetication`?

Comment: It doesn't assume, a SQL Server installation always contains a `master` database. If you can't login it's because you have no permissions. Either you have disabled Windows authentication or someone else installed the server and didn't add any other users. Moreover, permissions are granted first at the server level, then at the database level.

Comment: Try to run SQL Server Management Studio with elevated permissions (right-click > Run as Administrator).

Comment: I have added some more details to installation. It does not help run run Management Studio as Administrator

Comment: Your first image says that SQL server administrator is: "NETWORK SERVICE".
Did you added a group, a user, or "current user"? If not this is the problem: you are not NETWORK SERVICE, so you are not authorized.

Comment: No I did not I assumed that I could use a local service account for accessing the DB. Seems it not possible and that I have to re-install MSSQL or buy some software to update the password for the (hidden) sa user - see my edited post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login failed for user (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:18456) SQL Server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760919/login-failed-for-user-microsoft-sql-server-error18456-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://sqlserver-help.com/2012/02/08/help-i-lost-sa-password-and-no-one-has-system-administrator-sysadmin-permission-what-should-i-do/). You basically do following things.

1. Open SQL Server single user mode
2. Connect with sqlcmd
3. Add Necessary user as administrator.

> USE [master]
>
> GO
>
> CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\Administrators] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
>
> GO
>
> EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N’BUILTIN\Administrators’, @rolename = N’sysadmin’
>
> GO

[Article I linked](http://sqlserver-help.com/2012/02/08/help-i-lost-sa-password-and-no-one-has-system-administrator-sysadmin-permission-what-should-i-do/) gives step by step how to do those points.

Comment: What is SQL Server single user mode? Is that a client application?

Comment: @u123 read the link. You make it so that only SINGLE user can connect it.

Comment: Ok I will go and re-install windows server seems much faster

Comment: It won't be faster but I guess it doesn't hurt to find that out yourself.