# How to solve Unable to connect to SQL Server Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

Forgive me if my question is stupid or something as far as I am newbie to the programming. This stack over flow article [Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541680/visual-studio-2013-and-asp-net-web-configuration-tool) saved me days for running the Visual Studio 2013 WSA Tool but I run into a new problem and it is the connection to SQL Server database.

The problem is when I run IIS Express through cmd and then put address in browser I get redirected to WSA Tool but when I hit the security tab or link then I get this error:

> There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem:

> Unable to connect to SQL Server database

My connection string looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=aspnetdb; User Id=sa; Password=***********; Integrated Security=true" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And the whole my application `web.config` is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=aspnetdb; User Id=sa; Password=***********; Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I see no `<rolemanager enabled=true>`in my MVC Application, even though i tried a web application which have had this `<rolemanager enabled="true">`but didn't work even.

P.S: Worth to mention that when i run the application it self it works more than fine, i can create users, update users passwords and etc... and the results are reflected back to the MS SQL Server Database tables too but don't know what is the magic here.

What do you advise?!

Regards
Dostdar

Comment: take a look at the following link to see how to format the connection string in your .config file [C# Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: Is your SqlServer in [Mixed authentication mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393654/how-can-i-change-from-sql-server-windows-mode-to-mixed-mode-sql-server-2008) ?

Comment: Yes it is on Mixed Windows and SQL Server authentication mode

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to connect to your SQL Server as sa, then try removing 'Integrated Security=true' from your connection string.

When it is set to true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication. Your Windows user might not have appropriate rights to the DB.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I changed that but it didn't work even. I added my current Windows user ID during installation of the MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to go to sql server and in the object explorer search security -> sa -> status -> login -> enabled

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your connection string below, you are pointing to a local full blown SQL Server installation instance but do you really have a database named `aspnetdb` there? since you mentioned that in your connection string `Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;`.

The `aspnetdb` you are trying to access is a ASP.NET Identity database and I strongly doubt it's a attached database in your solution/project under `App_Data` folder. In which case, your connection string is wrong (you should be pointing to a `localDB` rather) and so you are facing the error.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=aspnetdb; ...
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: yes i do have sql db named aspnetdb and i don't have any attached database in my `App_Data`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Change `web.config` connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Your PC Name; Initial Catalog=aspnetdb; User Id=sa; Password=***********; " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

eg. Data Source=`XYZ\SQLEXPRESS` and try to remove 
`Integrated Security=true`