# How to Save ASP Net Membership Provider UserId into another sql table?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to get and Save ASP NET MVC Membership provider UserProfile table UserId field into a separate table?

Here is my model

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

}
```

I don't want to add UserId field into my Model anymore.
and here is my controller:

```
private UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
// GET: /ProCont/
int UserID = (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Products.Where(p => p.UserId == UserID).ToList());
}
```

What to do?

Regards
Dostdar

Comment: @Rahul, I have a product table where the users can enter their product the problem i faced was that when a user logged on he/she could see all users Product. i wanted to prevent that then i add a UserId in my model class and then used a where class in my controller class to prevent other users to view the other user products. now when i create a product i have to put the UserId for each product entry and that is a headache. i don't want that instead i want to this automatically when a user logged in and wants to create a product the user id should automatically get and save to database.

Comment: What you have currently is the right way to do it else there is no way you can relate a product with a specific user. This is what called as referential integrity. Here `userid` in your model class is acting as `FOREIGN KEY`. You just can't do it automatically.

Comment: @rahul how? tell me more as far as i am newbie to the MVC?

Comment: It's not about MVC rather about DB concept. At the end those Model going to represent DB entities and so, if you don't have userid in products table then try relating a product to a user and see if you can do so. That will give you an idea what I am saying.

Comment: Okay @Rahul i will let this UserId in my Model class but what i am not clear about is how to save this UserId automatically when a user wants to create a Product? I couldn't get your code?

Comment: I Have this in product create method, how would you edit this? @Rahul
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Products.Add(product);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(product);
        }

Comment: Give a moment .... check answer after some time.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I don't know how to do it in Comment.

Comment: @NaserDostdar it was my edit review, I was only formatting your post some, sorry for the minimal description...., however instead of using comment to improve your post, consider editing it....

Comment: @NaserDostdar, I have added a separate answer with code fragment to show you how to add it. Check it.

Comment: @PetterFriberg No worries, Sure it is a good point i'll do it in my next question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** It will be too long as a edit in already existing answer and hence posted in separate answer.

To answer your question on *how will you add the `UserID` field in your model object* below is a detailed description with code segment.

Considering that you have already added `Products` entity using `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`. Add a separate class file to your `Models` folder with any name you like and have the below code. Below code segment decorate your model object.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(productMetadata))]
    public partial class Product
    {

    }

    public class productMetadata
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        // to make the field hidden and will not display in browser
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        //directing that don't scaffold this column since it will be added manually
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You can directly modify the auto-generated `Product` class in EF but if you re-generate the EF model again then the changes will be gone. So, above shown approach is best using `MetadataType` attribute.

**Controller Action Method(s):**

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ProductName, ProductId")]Product product) 
    {
        SampleContext db = new SampleContext();

        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            product.UserId = (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
            db.Products.Add(product); 
            db.SaveChanges(); 
            return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
        } 

        return View(product); 
    }

    public ActionResult List()
    {
        SampleContext db = new SampleContext();
        IEnumerable<Product> products = db.Products.ToList();
        return View(products);
    }
}
}
```

**View (Specifically the Create view):**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Product

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Product</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Notice that the view has editable controls for only `productname` as input field since `ProductID` is an identity column and `UserID` getting value in code and not from user.

Comment: there are no words to thank you with! What an answer to the point and simple. Thanks a lot just appreciate your efforts!

Comment: Would you please solve this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535818/how-to-solve-unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-database

Answer (score 0):

It's really not clear what you are asking here? But are you saying that you want to store the `UserID` into your `Products` table in database. Then you can designate your model class so like below

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnotations.Table("Products")]
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

Either you can create the table `Products` manually or you can use `EF code first Migrations` to create a snapshot and update the database in order to add the newly created table.

Then you can add data to your table like

```
Product p1 = new Product
{
  UserID = (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey,
  ProductName = "XXX";
};

db.Products.Add(p1);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Per your comment:

What you have currently is the right way to do it else there is no way you can relate a product(s) with a specific user. This is what called as `Referential Integrity Constraint`. Here `UserID` in your model class is acting as `FOREIGN KEY`. You just can't do it automatically.

Comment: I am Using EF Migrations how can i just add that UserId to my table i couldn't catch this @Rahul