# How connect Weka to MSSQL server

Tags: sql-server, database, jdbc, odbc, weka

I want to connect to MSSQL server in **Weka 3.8**. I tried lots of things and I couldn't find a way to connect to **SQLServer 2012 Database**.

**Error:** *driver not found.*

I applied all steps about **JDBC-ODBC bridge** (link below)

https://andersspur.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/connect-weka-to-sql-server-2012-and-14/

**ErrorImage :**
 [image]

Comment: no errors during the tutorial? please add some more details, some code which you use for connecting to db..

Comment: Download and install this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt683464%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I know it is late, but I had the same problem, and this took me a while to find the solution. I am almost sure you found the solution. In here, it is the second step. However, I am sharing my approach and hope you and other find this helpful.

First, you need to download jdbc driver from Microsoft as you did. For me: [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=11774)

Second, make sure you have enabled TCP/IP connection. More info is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port) and [here](https://www.spdockit.com/support/help/faq/troubleshooting-sql-server/configure-sql-server-listen-specific-port/),

Third, enable Remote connection in SQL server instance, See [here](http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/).

Fourth, enable mix security mode in SQL, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393654/how-can-i-change-from-sql-server-windows-mode-to-mixed-mode-sql-server-2008), You may need to restart the sql engine. Integrated security may alos work for you. In this case, see how to set parameters [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url), Add a user and give it access to db you want.

Fifth, Follow these steps in [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4630/connecting-weka-to-sql-server-2016/) or [here](https://andersspur.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/connect-weka-to-sql-server-2012-and-14/), as you mentioned.

Sixth, Press this button, 
[image]
go to this address 'C:\Program Files\Weka-3-8\weka\experiment' and select 'DatabaseUtils.props', You should have edited this file in Fifth and this path may be different on your computer.

**Updated**
You may need to copy the modified `DatabaseUtils.props` into `wekafiles` folder possibly located  `C:\Users\myUser\wekafiles` for Weka 3.8 as suggested by Ivan

Seventh, Press this button and hope you can successfully connect to sql server.

[image]

This worked for me as shown here.
[image]

Comment: My pleasure, Glad you have found it helpful.

Comment: Yes, one consideration was I had to copied my modified 'DatabaseUtils.props' into C:\Users\myUser\wekafiles. For Weka 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

I installed JDBC Driver from msdn. But I couldn't find solution. Also I looked for the solutions which are defined in link below. Non of them is a problem in my case.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/10/sql-server-jdbc-error-tcpip-connection-to-host-failed-port-1433.html

Here ise the error:
exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host WAREHOUSE, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".