# Weka 3.8 - SQL Server connection

Tags: sql-server, weka

I have installed Weka 3.8 on my computer (windows 10) and I would like to connect it to my SQL server database.

I have followed the advice in this post:
[How connect Weka to MSSQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586148/how-connect-weka-to-mssql-server)

I can connect to the database and run queries and data is returned:

[image]

Although when I click "OK" to import the retrieved data from the database into Weka I get this error:

[image]

I have tried changing the DatabaseUtils.props (originally DatabaseUtils.props.mssqlserver2005 then renamed to DatabaseUtils.props) file to include the datatype conversions and tried many locations on my PC one being :
C:\Program Files\Weka-3-8\weka\experiment

Yet I still get the error. My file looks like this:

[image]

This seems like a common issue yet I am yet to see a definitive answer so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting DatabaseUtils.props in user.home (C:\Users\Oliver\ ?) or the current directory (in Eclipse current directory is project folder that contains src folder).

For details check https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/databases/#configuration-files