# “Login failed for user...” C# with SQLConnection

Tags: c#, sql-server

I try to connect to Sql server database, but it said :
“Login failed for user _cben” 
for line :

```
  sqlCon.Open();
```

this is my code :

```
   public static DataTable GetDataFromSqlDatabase(Dictionary<string, object> parameters, string nameOfStoredProcedure, string connectionString)
    {
        DataTable results = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            using (SqlCommand sqlCom = sqlCon.CreateCommand())
            {
                sqlCom.CommandText = nameOfStoredProcedure;
                sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                    
                BuildSQLCommandParams(parameters, sqlCom);
                results.Load(sqlCom.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
```

and my connection string :

```
     string connstr = "Data Source=CH-SQLDWV005;Initial Catalog=PWCGFA_COMMON;User ID=_cben;Password=_c...";

  return DataProviderUtility.GetDataFromSqlDatabase(sqlParams, StoredProcedures.GETREASSESSMENTS,connstr);
```

but when I add a sql file, the connection works and it brings me results
[image]

Comment: Can you ping the server `CH-SQLDWV005`? Is the sql server on the same machine where you execute the C# code?

Comment: Look in the SQL Server log, that will tell you the reason, E.g. SQL Auth is not enabled.

Comment: This is a common error message that doesnt really lie/mislead (as some do). If you open Sql management Studio, and try to connect to that server instance with that username/password what happens?

Comment: Yes I can ping to the server, PS : in .sql file I use windows authetication

Comment: @BKChedlia thats probably your answer. SQLAuthentication (ie, using an explicit username/password) is not enabled by default. You actually have to turn it on.

Comment: Does your user `_cben` have the rights? Try to connect in SQl management studio by using the same credentials as the connection string.

Comment: Try to enable mixed mode in your sql server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393654/how-can-i-change-from-sql-server-windows-mode-to-mixed-mode-sql-server-2008

Comment: I can open management studio only with windows authetication

Comment: Connect with  windows authetication and enable mixed mode

Comment: under security, Sql and windows authetication is checked but It doesn't work

Comment: It should be `Sql Server and Windows Authentification mode`

Comment: yes it is, sorry I didn't write the hole sentence... but it is checked

Comment: Then go under Security and create a user and give it the permission. Use that your user in your connection string.

Comment: thanks @billybob, now the password is not complex enough error  15118 , I will fix this then I will let you know if it's ok

Comment: @BKChedlia: Post the answer when your done plz.

Comment: @billybob thanks for help it works !!!