# Sql Server 2012 enterprise "sa" login failed. Error: 18456

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-10, sa

SQL server 2012. Windows 10 Professional.

I enabled "sa" user account, and the authentication mode is set to "windows authentication and SQL server authentication". I set the password for "sa user account". but I cannot login into it. Error: 18456.
[image]

I can successfully login into windows authentication.

"sa" system administrator account status enabled.
[image]

I found many duplicate questions, but none solved the issue.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances installed?  Are you sure you're connecting to the right instance?

Comment: The only instance ID I know while installing the sql server was "MSSQLSERVER", I added my current administrator desktop accounts for authorizations. Am I connected to the right instance? Here is what I found in the error log file: Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 58. Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication only. [CLIENT: <local machine>]. I have the sa account set to both windows and sql server authentication mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the authentication mode of your SQL-Instance to "mixed"  (SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode.).

If you just changed it you need to restart the SQL-Server service.

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode) the MS-documentation and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393654/how-can-i-change-from-sql-server-windows-mode-to-mixed-mode-sql-server-2008) an SO-answer.

Comment: its set to "sql server and windows authentication mode".

Comment: @AverageJoe The error-message is telling something different. If you just changed it you need to restart the SQL-Server service.

Comment: thanks, I had it set to mix mode, like hours ago. but didn't know nothing about the restarting the service! it worked.

Comment: Glad it works. When u change it and click on ok, a message pops up saying that you need to restart service ;-)

Comment: it did restarted, but now I did from the services, it worked properly. didn't work before. should I check this answer correct?

Comment: The service restart should work from SSMS too. I guess there was a additional problem when you tested the first time. If you think my answer is correct, then please. :-)